# auditd.conf - when is "verify_email" actually checked?

Tags: auditd

When using an email address in [/etc/audit/auditd.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/auditd.conf.5.html), there is an option **verify_email** which is defined as,

> This option determines if the email address given in action_mail_acct is checked to see if the domain name can be resolved. This option must be given before action_mail_acct or the default value of yes will be used.

When is the actual check performed?  For example, when the service is started? When an audit event occures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the service is started – or more precisely **during parsing the configuration**.

In the [`src/auditd-config.c`](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/src/auditd-config.c) (as of [60477a5](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/60477a539987dd4ab9e90e22e988ae0514d12076/src/auditd-config.c)):

- Configuration parameter `action_mail_acct` is parsed on lines 1124-1145.

  - There, if `config->verify_email` (as parsed from configuration parameter `verify_email = yes`) is `true` & `validate_email(tmail)` returns any errors, the `action_mail_acct_parser()` will `return 1`.
- The `validate_email()` on lines 1058-1122 performs various (quite naive) checks:

  1. Is the string too short to be an email address.
  2. Does the email address have illegal characters.
  3. Does the email address have `@` as it should.
  4. Does the email address have `.` after `@`.
  5. Uses [`getaddrinfo()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) to check whether the hostname part of the address resolves.
- On lines 1109-1111 there is a nice TODO left for detecting permanent failures.
  *Should I fix it now that I'm here? ;D*